# k8s, Ingress, Minio, and a Static Site

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, static-site, nginx-ingress, minio

We have a k8s cluster with an nginx Ingress and Minio installed. In Minio I have a bucket called `tester` with a hello world `index.html` file. I used the Minio MC client to set the `tester` bucket to public. Now I am able to see the hello world file when I visit my (altered) minio url like so: `https://minio.example.com/tester/index.html`.

My goal is to set up an Ingress resource to access the public bucket. Here is my manifest to try and do so, however I only ever get a 404 error . . .

`ingress.yaml`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-site
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    type: "frontend"
    awesomeness: "super-mega"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: app.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /tester/
            backend:
              serviceName: minio-svc
              servicePort: 9000
          - path: /tester/*
            backend:
              serviceName: minio-svc
              servicePort: 9000
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - app.example.com
      secretName: ssl-certs
```

I have also tried to set the paths with the index fileto no avail like so:

```
path: /tester/index.html
path: /tester/index.html/*
```

I do have another Ingress which points to Minio in general and it works perfect at the url like `minio.example.com`. The minio has a service called `minio-svc` on port 9000.

Unfortunately I have only ever received a 404 from my Ingress thus far. Anyone else deploying static sites with Ingress to public Minio bucket? What am I doing wrong???

**Updates**

So I kind of got somewhere. I added an annotation and  set the paths to simply `/` and `/*`.

Here is my new config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-site
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    type: "frontend"
    awesomeness: "super-mega"
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /tester/index.html
spec:
  rules:
    - host: app.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: minio-svc
              servicePort: 9000
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: minio-svc
              servicePort: 9000
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - app.example.com
      secretName: ssl-certs
```

Now I just get access denied from Minio even though the bucket is public and I can still access from `https://minio.example.com/tester/index.html`!?

Comment: Have you tried to split ingress into two resources with different names and paths for the same service entry point?

Answer (score 1):

Found out you can't do what I'm asking very easily. I got around it all by simply mounting the directory from the bucket directly to Nginx. Voila!

Comment: Can you share your config nginx for routing to minio static files?